# Convert byte[] to HttpWebResponse

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp, httpwebresponse

I'm writing tcp worker on raw sockets, which simply exchanges http traffic with server. Using raw sockets is, unfortunately, obligatory.
So far on the output there is a byte[] array that looks this way:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Thu, 21 Mar 2013 00:58:11 GMT
Transfer-Encoding:  chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Connection: Transfer-Encoding


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html lang="en" xml:lang="en" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org
...
```

and so on. Question is - can I somehow convert this byte[] array (or its string representation, or any other) into HttpWebResponse? Or maybe there's a way to pass sockets as a stream to WebResponse?

Desperate for any answer,
Dolla

Comment: The [manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.aspx) says: _"You should never directly create an instance of the HttpWebResponse class. Instead, use the instance returned by a call to HttpWebRequest.GetResponse"_. I think the class isn't intended to parse arbitrary HTTP responses. I'd also do that and really ditch sockets, because you really don't want to re-implement an HTTP client. Why the sockets only limitation?

Comment: Well, maybe you could suggest any other option on how to use ipv6 over ipv4 through .Net? So far I understand - you can create
    Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.IPv6);
It'll give you a protocol 41 - ipv4 header with "Next header = IPv6". Everything that is after this ipv4 header (ipv6 header, tcp header, data) should be constructed manually.
Do I miss something? =)